Issue with datetime after updating packages
I've updated to python 3.12.4 and I'm getting an error on the code:
test=pd.DataFrame(['2024-09-10 15:40:27+00:00','2024-09-10 18:13:50.201000+00:00']) 
pd.to_datetime(test[0]).dt.tz_localize(None) 

The error states:
ValueError: time data "2024-09-10 15:40:27+00:00" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z", at position 653.

I don't get this error on my laptop with an older python.
I've tried adding format='ISO8601' but this causes problems for my older code (which I still need).
How can I get it to work on both?

Make a [mcve] so we can diagnose the problem.

The error is generated from code not shown, but the time data doesn't match.  there are no decimal point and no fractional seconds to match .%f.

test=pd.DataFrame(['2024-09-10 15:40:27+00:00','2024-09-10 18:13:50.201000+00:00'])
pd.to_datetime(test[0]).dt.tz_localize(None)
this code works fine on my old python packages, but not on my desktop with new packages
